# search functionality from listviews in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have android tablet application which contains 2 list views with almost 50 different user names and on the top of that page I have a search bar. In that search bar if I enter a username or id it should search for the entered data from the 2 listviews and should display me those items belong to the data.I want to get this using javascript i don't want to use jquery as i have problem with 1.0.1.min.css file of jquery mobile i.e,this css is disturbing my existing UI so i want to acheive this using javascript.can anyone help me in solving this issue? any working examples are really helpful to me.

thank you.